# Customizing Ubiquity

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, ubiquity

I'm working on the installation of my Lubuntu respin (based on 20.04.1) and have it working well (e.g. all of the GRUB stuff works).

So now I'm turning my attention to the UX. It seems to me that Ubiquity works in 2 stages: First, it gathers information and then shows html pages while actually copying files.

I've found ubiquity-slideshow and have successfully changed the text and images to something more suitable for my product.

Now I'd like to make small changes to the way information is being gathered. In particular:

- Don't even ask about language choice - force English
- Don't ask about Updates and other software
- Don't ask the user for name, pasword, etc. I'd like to set those things

I can't figured out how to customize that stage of Ubiquity. Everything I've found seems to be ancient/obsolete. What do I need to look at?

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 uses the `calamares` installer, only releases up to and included Lubuntu 18.04 used `ubiquity`.  Yes some steps outside of the installer do refer to it as `ubiquity` (the standard for all Ubuntu desktop & *flavors*), but careful of your mixing of the two different programs.

Comment: @guiverc  Hmmmm, didn't know that. The 5 year old script that I'm using to create my respin .iso is based on Ubiquity so perhaps I'll keep that, Is there a good reason to switch to calamares and if so, will it be hard to figure out how to set it up? Can I keep may ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu, I have that set up just right,